# Make Button Disabled when the user clicks on the button and reaches at the Bottom or Top

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I have a issue like, I need to make the buttons disabled when the user clicks on the buttons 'Move TOP ' and 'Move Bottom' and scrolls to the respective direction based on some pixels, and when he reacehs Top or bottom of the Buttons, Make the button disabled.

You can make out the idea here
[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uptx23wc/11/)

```
$scope.scrollBtns = {
    downDisabled: true,
    upDisabled: false
};
$scope.scrollLogTable = function(topBottom) {
    var scroll_clipper = document.getElementById('scroll_clipper');
    var scrollBy = scroll_clipper.offsetHeight / 2;
    console.log("===========" + topBottom + "====================");
    if (topBottom === 'top') {
        console.log(scroll_clipper.offsetHeight)
        console.log(scroll_clipper.scrollTop, scrollBy)
        $scope.scrollBtns.upDisabled = false;
        var old = scroll_clipper.scrollTop;
        scroll_clipper.scrollTop = scroll_clipper.scrollTop - scrollBy;
        if (scroll_clipper.scrollTop == 0) {
            // we still have some scrolling to do...
            $scope.scrollBtns.downDisabled = false;
        } else {
            if (scroll_clipper.scrollTop < old) {
                // we have reached rock top
                //console.log('scroll_clipper.scrollTop < old if', scroll_clipper.scrollTop < old);
                $scope.scrollBtns.downDisabled = true;
            } else {
                //console.log('scroll_clipper.scrollTop < old else', scroll_clipper.scrollTop < old);
                $scope.scrollBtns.downDisabled = false;
            }
        }

    } else {

        $scope.scrollBtns.downDisabled = false;
        var old = scroll_clipper.scrollTop;
        scroll_clipper.scrollTop = scroll_clipper.scrollTop + scrollBy;
        if (scroll_clipper.scrollTop > scrollBy) {
            console.log("we still have some scrolling to do...");
            $scope.scrollBtns.upDisabled = true;
        } else {
            console.log('scroll_clipper.scrollTop  > scrollBy', scroll_clipper.scrollTop > scrollBy)
            console.log("we have reached rock bottom");
            $scope.scrollBtns.upDisabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Logic to make disabling the 'Move Top' and 'Move Bottom' when it reaches the bottom or top is not happening

Can any one here can help me out.

NOTE:

1. The size of the div may increase its size, as it depends on DB.
2. I do not want to use jquery

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The angular-way would be to create a directive that controls this behavior and calls a method when the container is scrolled.

```
angular.module('app').directive('watchScroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            onTop: '&',
            onBottom: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {
            var container = angular.element(elements[0]);
            var onScroll = function () {
                var scrollY = elements[0].scrollTop;
                var maxScrollY = elements[0].scrollHeight - elements[0].offsetHeight;
                if (scrollY <= 0) {
                    scope.onTop();
                }
                if (scrollY >= maxScrollY) {
                    scope.onBottom();
                }
            };
            container.on('scroll', onScroll);
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                container.off('scroll', onScroll);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and then use this directive on your elements.

```
<div watch-scroll on-top="callYourFunction()" on-bottom="callYourFunction()"></div>
```

Quick and dirty fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6uxhy08/

Comment: I am so sorry to confuse, I edited my text/question, What I wanted is the buttons will perform the operation of scrolling in either direction, and once it reaches the TOP or BOTTOM div, the corresponding button should get disabled, because there is no purpose of make it enabled.

Comment: I will post a different solution to your problem when I am back at my PC. For now you could try this approach as it is broader and I think cleaner.

Comment: Actually I have looked at your code, and I would highly recommend that you atleast try this approach (with a directive component). The intent is clearer and it is reusable. Which is always nice.